# Can't access to admin console after forcing wildfly 14 to use ssl on the port 443

Tags: linux, ssl, port

I deployed wildfly to my server on a subdomain and Nginx is a reverse proxy.To secure my connection I forced wildfly to use https through 443 with a letsencrypt ssl certificate :

In the standalone.xml, I create an additional socket-binding entry. and I added a

```
<socket-binding name="https-external" port="443"/>
```

and I Changed the http-listener to redirect this https-external instead https.

It worked fine until the moment when I tried to access the admin console: I was unable to login.

I tried to modify the management-interfaces by adding a socket-binding with http="management-http**s**"(and by default it uses the port 9993 for the management-https) but it didn't work.
It looks that I'm missing something which I can't figure out.

the content of the "vhost" file of wildfly subdomain for ngnix is :

```
upstream wildflyadmin {
    server 127.0.0.1:9990;
}
upstream wildfly {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
    server_name sub.domaine.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/wildfly.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/wildfly.error.log;

    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

location / {
              proxy_pass http://wildfly;  
    }

location /dashadmin/ {
              proxy_pass http://wildflyadmin;  
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domaine.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domaine.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened after i used a backup file of the standalone.xml.  By default, wldfly doesn't allow foreign access to its management console.

So the management interface should be changed to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

```
<interfaces>
  <interface name="management">
  <inet-address value="0.0.0.0"/>
...
```